# Can you run PHP webpages from any location?

Tags: php, windows, localhost, wamp, wampserver

I have just installed WampServer64 on Windows 10. By default, if you want to run a PHP webpage you have to put it in a project directory in `C:\wamp64\www`. However, this is inconvenient for me as normally projects live in my GitHub directory `C:\Users\<user>\GitHub`. Is it possible to run a PHP webpage that lives in a directory in this GitHub folder?

Comment: yes. you can create either an "alias" or a "virtual directory". On the trayIcon go to Apache - > alias directories -> add an alias

Comment: try editing the apache configuration files

Comment: [here's a simple explanation I've found as first hit](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smb-technologist/create-aliases-on-your-wamp-server/)

Comment: @Jeff Thanks, aliases was exactly what I was hoping for

Comment: Virtual hosts is what you need to look at See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Comment: @RiggsFolly I disagree, Aliases was what I was after. And much simpler than the lengthy highest-voted Virtual Host answer in the marked duplicate

Comment: It takes 2 minutes to create a Virtual Host in WAMPServer 3